# What are games for GameBoy Color known as?

Tags: terminology, game-boy

I want to know if the games for GameBoy Color are considered to be 16-bit games? If not, what category do they fall under?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, they would be considered 8-bit because this bit rating relates to the processor. Using the terms 8-bit or 16-bit for example refers to the console itself rather than the games that can be played on them.

[See here for the Gameboy colour specs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_Boy_Color), you can see the processor is 8-bit.

This term could be confused with the colour palette available, which again from the link above, show the Gameboy colour to have a 15-bit colour palette. However, this is not a factor for the term in question. The increased colour palette is most likely available due to an increase in memory from previous Gameboy editions rather than anything else.

Comment: Ahh, I saw that page before but thought it was referring to the `Palette colors available` so `15-bit` and since I'm not aware of such a thing as 15-bit, I thought it was a typo.

Comment: Edited a brief bit about that too